# Core6, EFCore, and scaffolding

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have just created a brand new project in Visual Studio 2022.  The project is targeting .NET 6.0, EF Core 6.0.7, and I have added the tools package so I can attempt to scaffold my existing database.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWindowsForms>True</UseWindowsForms>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <UseWPF>False</UseWPF>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.7">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.7" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.7">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <!--<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.7" />-->
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

You will notice that one line is commented out (...DotNetCliToolReference...), more on that in a minute.

When I try my scaffolding command, I am told that the command is not available, either via the PowerShell command or by the standard `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold ...` command.

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
> Possible reasons for this include:
>
> - You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
> - You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
> - You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

THe command I am running is:
`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

With some research I discovered and added the `DotNetCliToolReference` line to add to my project file.  After I add that I am immediately greeted with a new error.

> NU1202 Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.7 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.2 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 6.0.7 supports: net6.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0)

As you can see from my project file, I am not running .NET Core v2.2!!!

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.NET tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools) aren't installed using `DotNetCliToolReference`. That's [only used up to .NET Core 2.2](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3115). The EF docs *don't* mention it at all.

.NET Tools are managed with the `dotnet tool` command. You can see all the available commands and options with `dotnet tool --help`.

Tools are published as NuGet packages in NuGet.org. They can be installed with

```
dotnet tool install --global tool-name
```

The [EF tool docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#installing-the-tools) show that the correct command is

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
```

Upgrading works the same as other dotnet tools

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

Scaffolding in general is explained in the [Reverse Engineering (Scaffolding)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) page